# TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined react-native-camera-roll

Tags: react-native

I've been trying to use camera-roll to save a qr code from RN app, the problem is when using CameraRoll it's undefined.

I tried manual linking by following the doucmentation, but it didn't work. I even tried to add the camera's package in MainApplication.java but I get the following error

> Native module RNCCameraRoll tried to override com.reactnativecommunity.cameraroll.Camera RollModule. Check the getPackages() method in MainApplication.java, it might be that module is being created twice. If this was your intention, set canOverrideExistingModule=true. This error may also be present if the package is present only once in getPackages() but is also automatically added later during build time by autolinking. Try removing the existing entry and rebuild.

it's an old project so it's using RN 0.6.5 and gradle-6.7.1.
I also tried `react-native link @react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll`, for IOS it works but I get the following error for android `error Linking "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll" failed. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'path_to_project\android\app\src\main\java\com\name_of_project\android\MainApplication.java' at Object.openSync (node:fs:590:3)` 
the error is correct since the correct path is 'path_to_project\android\app\src\main\java\com\name_of_project\MainApplication.java'

I've used the latest version of the package, then tried with 5.6.0, 5.5.0, 5.0.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.